# Не удаётся запустить программу - не соответствуют архитектуры

Tags: c#, .net-core, monogame

При запуске программы в Visual Studio 2019 выдаётся ошибка : "MSB3270   несоответствие между архитектурой процессора проекта "MSIL", сборка которого выполняется, и архитектурой процессора ссылки "PresentationCore", "x86". Это несоответствие может привести к ошибкам во время выполнения. Рекомендуется изменить целевую архитектуру процессора для проекта с помощью диспетчера конфигураций, чтобы согласовать архитектуры процессоров для проекта и ссылок, или использовать зависимость от ссылок с архитектурой процессора, соответствующей целевой архитектуре процессора проекта."

пробовал изменять целевые платформы на х86, х64 и х32 - не помогло. Как исправить?

Comment: .csproj файл покажете? А пока ответить не получится, потому что ваш вопрос звучит как "У меня болит нога. Пробовал сидеть, стоять и лежать - не помогло. Как вылечить?"

Comment: Что именно вы сделали, после чего перестало запускаться?

Comment: @aepot , добавил ссылку на System.Windows.Extensions. Удалять невозможно т.к. тогда не будет нужного функционала

Comment: и какой именно функционал вам нужен? какую версию дотнета вы используете? какой тип приложения? вы тегов понаставили про Visual Studio, но вопрос к IDE не относится. А нужных тегов нет.

Comment: @aepot , у меня .NET Core 2.1, мне нужен звук для monogame, пробовал другие .dll - выдаются похожие ошибки.

Comment: Разрядность и архитектура ЦП всех зависимых библиотек должна совпадать с разрядностью и архитектурой ЦП приложения, тогда ошибки не будет. Если ошибка выдается, значит разрядность не совпадает.

Comment: @aepot , а возможно это обойти? Потому что System.Windows.Extensions не нахожу для другой архитектуры.

Comment: Нет, в рамках одного приложения не возможно.